# Is there a quick way to find out in which runtime package the Embarcadero unit was implemented?

Tags: delphi

Is there a quick way to find out in which runtime package the Embarcadero unit was implemented?
Help is silent. I am currently opening the package with AQtime.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new package, add a new unit and put the unit in question into its uses. Compile the package and if the unit is contained in any package that is being loaded by the IDE it will open a dialog suggesting to add this package to the requires clause of your package.

Comment: Thank you, but that is also complicated. We currently have around 280 projects to compile. The uniform project settings are set / overridden via TFSBuild. Many units are implicitly included. A simpler, more direct way of working would be more helpful for us.

Comment: Your comment gives a hint what you are actually after, but it is not clear enough. Can you explain your real problem you are trying to solve? Why do you need to know the runtime package containing some unit?

Comment: @UweRaabe I would like a simpler revision. Currently, it can only be seen indirectly whether the specified conditions are met. A **quick way** would be: "You can see it in the help and / or in the head of the unit or in another way, not yet known to me.

Comment: You are still not answering my question: _Why do you need to know the runtime package containing some unit?_

Comment: @UweRaabe It seems to me that some access violations are caused by the fact that the DLL contains code and not references from Embarcadero units.
If you are working across modules, you access unsuspecting this code even though the DLL that provides the code has already been unloaded. If a different runtime is required, this must be included in the build configuration. Evident looks different.

Comment: @UweRaabe: Today: call to REST.Json.TJson.JsonToObject -> ERangeError.

```
{"iAktMon":0,"nState":"wsMaximized","rBoundRect":[1672,170,3608,1226,[1672,170],[3608,1226]]}


 TPdfViewerSettings=class(TObject)
  public
    constructor Create;
  public
    FiAktMon   : integer;
    FnState    : TWindowState;
    FrBoundRect: TRect;
  public
    property iMonitor   : integer       read FiAktMon    write FiAktMon;
    property nState     : TWindowState  read FnState     write FnState;
    property rBoundRect : TRect         read FrBoundRect write FrBoundRect;
  end;
```

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to tell me with that comment.

Comment: To me this sounds very much like a case of an XY problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem